# Angular 2, Ionic 2

Tags: angularjs, ionic2

Am trying to display seconds in real-time.

This is what I have in the component.

```
//In the component
today: number = Date.now();
//the template
{{ today | date:'medium' }}
```

This displays the date and time, but the seconds can only change on refresh of the app.

I want to see change of seconds in real-time. Can someone please give a guide.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/moment

Comment: @Zaheer UI Hassan. Thanks, exactly what I wanted!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `setInterval` to refresh `today`, remember to clear the created interval in `ngOnDestory`. But be careful not using it too much for good performance.

```
private dateInterval: any;

constructor() {}

// add interval at OnInit
ngOnInit() {
  this.dateInterval = setInterval(() => {
    this.today = Date.now();
  }, 1000)
}

// destory interval at OnDestory
ngOnDestory() {
  clearInterval(this.dateInterval);
}
```

**[Plunker demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/hXD7qZCfU3tFr2Ucts28?p=preview)**

Comment: I think inside interval variable should out of scope.

Comment: @Math10 nope, zone.js has patched `setInterval`.

Comment: Than I did some thing wrong in my ionic2 code. Because I always need to define scope while using `setInterval` or `setTimeout`